# Godot exporting to Android

Tags: android, linux, godot

I'm trying to export from my Godot on LINUX system to Android. Godot reports that it cannot find the debug.keystore file. I've already checked the documentation and several tutorials and revised the versions and the problem persists. Would someone please have a solution or explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the release was not defined correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the debug.keystore path in the Editor Settings.
On the top left click on Editor -> Editor Settings -> Scroll down to Export -> Android and there you can set the debug.keystore path.

Comment: I did it according to your guidance and even so godot continues to report the same problem

Comment: I put this address but godot informs you that it can't find the file./home/elon/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: Did you create the keystore?
Try the steps listed [here](https://gist.github.com/henriquemenezes/70feb8fff20a19a65346e48786bedb8f#debug-keystore) to create one.

Comment: I talked to a Polish and a Frenchman and they explained the problem. It wasn't in the editor configuration. It was in the release that it wasn't defined correctly.